# Roles and Permissions between users and organizations

Tags: python, django, authorization, microservices

I'm building an application that allows users to belong to multiple organizations and can perform specific operations within each of these organizations as long as they have the required roles and permissions to do so. However, I kind of have issues implementing a satisfiable model that suits this requirement, especially given that roles and permissions in Django are typically related to the user's model and so it's impossible for them to vary with a particular user per organization. What I have done so far is implement a third model that records the role of a user with a particular organization in a separate table:

```
class OrgUserPerms(models.Model):
organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
user = models.ForeignKey("accounts.CustomUser", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
user_role = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=[
    ("organization_admin","admin"), 
    ("organization_manager", "manager"),
    ("organization_member", "member")
])
```

The problem with this model is that a user can have multiple OrgUserPerms referencing the same organization, I currently handle this by filtering the last saved OrgUserPerm object as the user's latest role in an organization then throw away the remaining OrgUserPerm objects with the same user&organization occurrence. I however feel this might eventually lead to operational bottlenecks in speed, security e.t.c and would deeply appreciate advice/suggestions from people with experience implementing something similar, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **ManyToManyField** on your **Organization** model to define the roles that users can have within an **organization**.

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    members = models.ManyToManyField("accounts.CustomUser", through="OrgMembership")

class OrgMembership(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey("accounts.CustomUser", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=[
        ("organization_admin","admin"), 
        ("organization_manager", "manager"),
        ("organization_member", "member")
    ])
```